# Installing python3.x-dev in a docker image of python:3.x-slim-buster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have a `python:3.9-slim-buster` docker image, and I want to install `python3.9-dev` in it which will throw an error at me.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
RUN apt update && apt install -y bash make git zip wget
<some other code Here>
RUN apt update && apt install -y libpq-dev gcc python3-dev python3-pip
```

here is the error I get:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3.9-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.9-dev'
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install -y libpq-dev gcc python3.9-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: Do you actually need to install python3.9-dev?  Why doesn't the Dockerfile as you have it above (with python3-dev) work?

Comment: so the code that I'm updating has 3.7-dev. I used 3-dev to fix the problem but thought maybe there is version-specific stuff in 3.9-dev that I might need to have.

Comment: The current version of python3-dev package for buster is 3.7 https://packages.debian.org/buster/python3-dev
It is probably possible to install the bullseye flavor of python3-dev (which is currently at 3.9 https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-dev), but it's generally not recommended to do that as it could cause issues https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian.  Unless you know you need python3.9-dev for some reason, it's probably not an issue